# How to clone/ create duplicate, set of fields in Apache wicket

Tags: jquery, wicket

I have a requirement where there is field set for adding and displaying existing comments. Design is, on top half, existing comments from db are displayed row wise, beneath that a separator line followed by a row with active input fields( date picket field, text area for comment and an Add button). Clicking Add button should add the latest comment entry made in the comment list above and clear the input fields.
I have successfully managed doing this using JQuery's clone method. However, I am not satisfied with this approach as I have not leveraged the wickets power as such here. I am new to the framework and to be honest still not very comfortable with rudimentary basics required to take full benefit of this framework. I will appreciate if someone can help with ideas ( better if you can give me some live example links, knowledge source etc) to achieve the task I mentioned using wicket.

HTML :

```
<DIV class=row>
    <!-- COMMENTS GRID WIDGET - BEGIN -->
    <DIV class=formField>
        <FIELDSET style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; PADDING-TOP: 5px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; WIDTH: 985px">
            <LEGEND>Comments</LEGEND>
            <DIV id=frmgrid1 style="HEIGHT: 130px">
                <div id="commentgrid">
                    <DIV style="OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: 130px">
                        <TABLE id="tblGridComment" class="tableData" width="955" border="0" >
                            <THEAD>
                            <TR bgColor=#eaeaea>
                                <TD class=tableTitle style="WIDTH: 100px" noWrap>Date</TD>
                                <TD class=tableTitle noWrap>Comment</TD>
                                <TD class=tableTitle style="WIDTH: 100px" noWrap
                                    align=center>Delete</TD>
                            </TR>
                            </THEAD>
                            <TBODY>
                            <TR bgColor="#ffffff" wicket:id="comrow">
                                <TD class="tableData commenttd" vAlign=top>
                                    <A href="#" wicket:id="comdtlink">
                                        <span wicket:id="comdt"> 12/12/12 </span>
                                    </A>
                                </TD>
                                <TD class="tableData commenttd" vAlign="top">
                                    <INPUT  wicket:id="exsistcomment"
                                            style="WIDTH: 750px" maxLength="2000" name="exsistcomment" />
                                </TD>
                                <TD class="tableData commenttd" vAlign=top>
                                    <INPUT type="checkbox" wicket:id="commdelete" name="commdelete"/>
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                            </TBODY>
                        </TABLE>
                    </DIV>
                    <HR width=955>
                </div> <!-- comment grid end -->
                <DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WIDTH: 955px">
                    <SPAN class=row>
                        <SPAN class=formField>
                            <label wicket:id="pdeffdatelabel">Effective Date: </label><BR>
                            <INPUT  wicket:id="pdeffdate" id="pdeffdate" name="pdeffdate" />
                            <!-- <A wicket:id="linkpdeffdate" href="#">
                            <IMG style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: text-bottom; MARGIN-LEFT: 2px"
                            border=0 alt="Select Comment Effective Date" src="cal.gif"
                            width=16 height=19 wicket:id="pdeffdateimg" id="pdeffdateimg">
                            </A> -->
                        </SPAN>
                        <SPAN class=formField>
                            <label wicket:id="pdcommentlabel">Comment: </label><BR>
                            <TEXTAREA   wicket:id="pdcomment" id="pdcomment" cols="94"
                                         name="pdcomment">
                            </TEXTAREA>
                        </SPAN>
                        <SPAN class=formField><BR> 
                            <INPUT id="addcomment"  title="Add Row" class="btnz"
                                   type="button" value=" Add " name="btnAddRowComment">
                        </SPAN>
                    </SPAN>
                </DIV>
            </DIV>
        </FIELDSET>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

JQuery :

```
 $("#addcomment").click(function () {
             console.log("djkdk");
             var sourcetr   =   $('[id^="commenttr"]').last();
             var clonetr    =   $(sourcetr).clone();    
             clonetr.insertAfter(sourcetr);
             var clonetrid = clonetr.attr("id"),
             res = "",
             newid = "";
             if(clonetrid != "") {  
                res = clonetrid.substring(9,clonetrid.length);
                newid = clonetrid.substring(0,9);
             }
             clonetr.attr('id',newid);
             clonetr.find('[id^="comdt"] span').text($('#pdeffdate').val());
             $('#pdeffdate').val("");
             clonetr.find('[id^="exsistcomment"]').val($('#pdcomment').val());
             $('#pdcomment').val("");
             clonetr.show();

         });
```

As per whatever I could find on internet, it seems I can use WebMarkupContainer to group rows and perhaps clone it somehow. I am not sure if its possible or not though.

Thanks for help.
Suvo

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView to generate repetitive elements

Go through following 
http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/repeaters.html

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply.
I have gone through ListView details. I dont inderstand how can I use it to clone a component on client side. As I understand, it requires a list for rendering before the request is returned. Please enlighten me on this. Thanks

Comment: try to think in JAVA style . Create a bean class{IModel in case of wicket} to store values of existing elements. Then use it to store value and filling value (rendering). Can you please provide a (working demo)jsfiddle ?